# Filtering null values on elasticsearch nested model

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a `Product` model and a `Sku` model, with a `Product` having multiple `Skus`.

Within elasticsearch, I can filter `Products` by `Sku` pricing with a query structured like so:

```
query:
  bool:
    must: [
      nested:
        path: 'skus'
        query:
          bool:
            must: [
              range:
                baseline_price:
                  gte: opts.min_price
                  lte: opts.max_price
            ]
    ]
```

However, I'm having trouble doing similar for `length`, `width`, and `height` values on the `Sku` model.

I'd like to find all `Skus` that don't have any of `length`, `width`, or `height`.  I'm trying things like:

```
query:
  bool:
    must: [
      nested:
        path: 'skus'
        query:
          bool:
            should: [
              exists: { field: 'length' }
              exists: { field: 'width' }
              exists: { field: 'height' }
            ]
    ]
```

Just to return anything useful, but any combination I have throws an error.  In the case above, it throws `No query registered for [exists]`

I've looked through the [documentation for null values in elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html), but still no luck.

How should I be writing this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it somewhat working like so:

```
query:
  bool:
    must: [
      nested:
        path: 'skus'
        query:
          constant_score:
            filter:
              bool:
                must: [
                  missing: { field: 'skus.width' }
                ]
    ]
```

This will find `Skus` with missing `width`. However, adding additional `length` or `height` fields unfortunately behaves as an `OR` instead of an `AND`, and I'm not sure whether this is a bug with elasticsearch or not.

This solves it well enough for our needs now, but still not sure if there is a way to filter by multiple missing fields.